# Swift 3 error with tableView

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

An error keeps occurring even changing the new swift3.0 syntax like removing the NS prefixes and other. The error says

cannot call value of non-function type `UITableView`

I'm glad if I could have a hint for solving this problem.

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
                return cell
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartcel", for: indexPath) as! cartTableViewCell // My custom tableview cell class 
      cell.productName.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproName
      cell.productQty.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproPrice
      cell.productAmount.text = Addtocartdata[indexPath.row].cartproPrice
      return cell;
 }
```

Comment: actually i don't have any custom cells.

Comment: ok then just access it with your tag and at last  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartcel", for: indexPath) as! UITableviewCell

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Songcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
     
  let eventname: UILabel = (cell.viewWithTag(7) as! UILabel)
 eventname.text = songnamearray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
      
        return cell
        
    }
Here is answer for swift 2.0 and xcode 7.3

Comment: sorry for asking again and again and for my unskilful explanation but i'm now trying to migrate to Swift3 and so the former answer of yours will sure be the answer. thanks

Comment: @ucb its ok buddy this site is for solve problem so you can ask question . is there my answer helpful to you then approve it thank you .

Answer (score 2):

You need to return cell because cellforRowAtIndexPath is non void function :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

  return cell
}
```